# When would response to a broadcast max out or flood single computer's nic?

Tags: udp, ip, broadcast

We are communicating bacnet which has a broadcast discovery which fortunately/unfortunately can support 4 million object ids.  In a broadcast message, I can specify the range of ids though.  Obviously if I do too large of a range like 4 million, many udp packets will be dropped which I really don't want.  Any idea of how many a good range would be?  I am thinking of broadcasting to ask for ranges of 1000 and doing that 4000 times.  Then I would do that once a week to pick up any new devices that come online.

Any ideas where that would get saturated?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Well, my single computer accepts around 200,000 udp packets / second.  It turns out I must be hitting a horrible network as no braodcast, and just direct point to point udp cannot do 100 requests at a time.  when I did 100 threads, all udp request/response timed out....doing 10 seems to work and I can probably push that up a little but either way, I must be hitting a really bad switch/hub/something that is really just not holding up to a very small load so regardless of braodcast, the network I was hitting is really bad.